# Generating a build from TFS

Tags: tfs, build-process

When you are going to release a build using TFS, what do you normally do?  Just use a specific changeset, create a branch or label/tag?

Note: this build is not for release, it is for our staging/user acceptance environment.

Answer (score 1):

The build system will automatically create a label based on the name.  Usually that is good enough for most companies.

Answer (score 0):

When we start development on a new version we branch and put new code and revisions in that branch.

This allows us to do two things:

1. We set up a nightly merge process that folds the branch back into the mainline.  This allows bug fixes to propagate to all versions in development (any other branches are merged from mainline and back again based on version number precedence).
2. We also set up a nightly build for each branch that is deployed in the morning to our staging environment.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pretty simple formula for deciding if it should be a label or a branch, if there is any chance you'll need to patch or hotfix the build then use a branch. Otherwise, if you'll just want to refer to the code at a certain point use a label. Another important consideration is that labels only have limited configuration manager, e.g. they can be deleted or modified by anyone with permission without any change history.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have more than one build.  I use the Versioning tasks that come with the free MSBuild packages (the MSBuild Community tasks, MSBuild Extension Pack and MSBuild SDC) to change my version in Team Build and in my binaries.

I have a custom version that is of the format 1.2.3.4 (major.minor.revision.build)

My nightly builds up the build number.  When I am going to do a release to testing I fire off a build that will up the revision number.

Then when you are ready for prod you can release the version that has passed testing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing nightly build as suggested above by @Vaccano or you could do continuous integration. You can find good build tools to get you off on right direction at http://www.newagesolution.net/SpecialEvents/SessionatOrlandoCodeCamp2009.aspx. There should be Powerpoint and code samples to achieve automated build and packaging.

Answer (score 0):

As part of nightly builds / scheduled builds, one would also like to generate release notes from the version control and workItems repository.

Having release notes handy is of great advantage. It's now possible to use [**TFS ChangeLog / TFS ReleaseNotes Generator**](http://tfschangelog.codeplex.com) from http://tfschangelog.codeplex.com project.

TFS ChangeLog application allows users to provide information about their changeset starting point and ending point (we call it as changeset range) and then it extracts information for each changeset that is present between starting and ending changesets. This extracted information is then saved in a XML file and then using XSLT 2.0 transformation, it generates HTML release notes report.

I hope this is of help.

Best Regards,

Dharmesh Shah.